# jquery getElementById on a ajax data

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest, clean-urls

I got a function in javascript that first checks if the username is the required length and than sends the username to a page for a test if the test is a success there will be a 
`<span id="username">true</span>`
else 
`<span id="username">false</span>`

I keep getting an error that getElementById doesn't exist on the return data

```
  function checkuser(user, wd,id, sub)
    {
        if(user.length < 7)
        {
            document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = "Your username is too short. It must be longer than 6 charaters";
            document.getElementById(sub).disabled = true;
            return false;
        } else {
            $.post(wd + "register/checkuser/" + user,
                       function(data){
                         alert("Data Loaded: " + data.getElementById('username').innerHTML;
                       });
        }
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting error with data.getElementById() ?

Comment: Change, `data.getElementById('username').innerHTML;` to  `document.getElementById('username').innerHTML = data;` Read @Amber's comment!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to do this:

```
function checkuser(user, wd, id, sub) {
  if(user.length < 7) {
    $("#"+id).html("Your username is too short. It must be longer than 6 characters");
    $("#"+sub).attr("disabled", true);
    return false;
  }
  else {
    $.post(
      wd + "register/checkuser/" + user,
      function(data){
        alert("Data Loaded: " + $(data).find("#username").html());
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The `data` return value is a string, not a DOMDocument - thus it doesn't have a getElementById member function.

A better idea would be to have your test page return JSON instead, and parse that.

If you can't change the page that does the testing/returning, then you'll need to find another way to parse the return string that serves your purposes.

Comment: `data` isn't *always* a string, is it? It depends on the response's type and whether you've set `dataType`: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/  It will be a string if the response is HTML, though, and JSON is absolutely the way to go for this kind of response.

Comment: But either way, it's a string or json data, but still isn't in the DOM and won't have a getElementById()

Comment: & Marc: I can't conveniently try it right now, but if you retrieve XML (or set `dataType`), don't you get a DOMDocument containing the XML document? (Attempts with JSBin failed, but that seems to be what the docs suggest.) Again, this is a side point, completely agree with Amber that JSON is the best way to go here.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
   function(data){
       alert( "Data Loaded: " + $('#username', data).html() );
   });
```

Or this, depending on the structure of the HTML returned:

```
   function(data){
       alert( "Data Loaded: " + $(data).filter('#username').html() );
   });
```